# WordPress Functions File Using PHP Class

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class

I am currently creating a WordPress functions.php file based off this blog article - http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/22/organize-wordpress-functions-file/

All working fine so far, however I'm stuck when trying to add the Theme Logo function (https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo)

```
function theme_prefix_the_custom_logo() {
    if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
        the_custom_logo();
    }
}
```

into the PHP class within the functions.php file.

I can't seem to call

```
<?php theme_prefix_the_custom_logo(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php $myTheme->theme_prefix_the_custom_logo(); ?>
```

from my front-page.php template file as i normally would. Any thoughts to where i should place this function within the class and how to make it available to template files within my theme?

Comment: you need to follow each process from these url https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo

Comment: like first you need to add the line of code **add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );**

Comment: I have the following in my functions file already @Mit.agile

`function __construct() {
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this, 'init' ) );
}
function init() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'width' => 640,'height' => 320,
        'flex-width' => true,
        'flex-height' => true,
        'header-text' => array('site-title', 'site-description')
    ) );
}`